# Need a geometric edge/crease detection method

Tags: algorithm, opengl-es, edge-detection

I am experimenting with a primitive rendering style (solid colors with highlighted edges/creases) for an open-source game I contribute to. The world geometry is fairly simplistic, and is mostly comprised of blocks, pyramids, and there may ultimately be other simple volumes like cylinders, cones, other kinds of prisms, etc. The rendering will be done with OpenGL ES 2.

I have been experimenting with edge detection methods for the edges/creases. It seemed like doing shader-based edge detection (I tried the sobel filter and several other algorithms) on the depth value and face normals would be easiest, but I was unable to get a good result, mostly due to the precision limits of the depth buffer and the complexity of far-away geometry, as well as the inability to do any good antialiasing on the edges.

I ultimately decided that I needed to render the lines geometrically so I could make them thick and smooth out the edges, etc. I would like to generate the lines programmatically from the geometry definition prior to rendering to improve runtime performance. I can get most of the effect I want by drawing the main geometry, set a depth offset, then draw lines over the geometry. However, this technique has some shortcomings, as seen below:

**Overlapping Geometry**

There may be several pieces of geometry overlapping or adjoining to form more complex structures. Where several pieces have overlapping/coplanar faces, I want to draw an outline around them but not around each individual piece so you can see each separate part.

Current result on top; desired result on bottom:

[image: overlap]

**Creases**

This issue was also visible in the image above, but the image below also shows what my goals are. I want to draw lines where there are creases in overlapping geometry to make them stand out a lot more.

Current result on top; desired result on bottom:

[image: creases]

---

From what I can tell so far, for the overlapping faces problem, I think I need to do intersection tests between my lines and any nearby intersecting faces, then somehow break the lines up and get rid of the segments that cross other faces. To create lines in the creases between geometry, I think I need to do some kind of intersection tests between the two faces that form the crease. However, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the step-by-step procedure for doing that. Again, I would like to set up these lines programmatically in a pre-rendering step if possible. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you're searching for in other words is silhouette lines.

Comment: try to look up some old wire-frame rendering techniques but I think you need to merge the meshes on CPU side before rendering or use some kind of stencil or alpha testing to remove lines from overlapping planes/faces. like render faces only but count how many faces per fragment is there (increment) and then render edges where `count == 1`

Comment: http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/opengl-detection-of-edges/2452 appears to have a few solutions that may point you in the right direction, especially the links further below.

Comment: @WLGfx Some interesting info there. I'm open to post-process techniques, but as I mentioned I didn't get good results due to depth buffer precision at long range. The single-pass shader-based approach looks great, but it requires knowledge of where the edges need to be on the CPU side, and that's what I needed to calculate to begin with.